# display an images directly from a directory on your computer in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, drawable

Is it possible to display an image directly from a directory on the computer (like from Local Disk C or D or My Documents) without storing it in the `drawable` folder? If yes then how?

Comment: sorry *an image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android :: Can I load files from any other folders than drawable or assets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012079/android-can-i-load-files-from-any-other-folders-than-drawable-or-assets)

Comment: I mean from a folder such as my documents from my computer using the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible 
1.Try This Code:

```
File imgFile = new  File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20151102_193132.jpg");//Your file path
  if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

  };
```

2.Also you need to add below permission to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

3. and for API 23+ you have to code for [Android Runtime Permission](https://www.journaldev.com/10409/android-runtime-permissions-example)